# Creating a ranking in Excel by matching values in non-contigous cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel file that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E        F  G  H  I  J      K  L  M  N  O  
1  Alice                Bob                Charles
2  10 35 54 9 21        71 15 43 75 98     13 35 66 80 20
```

where each group of 5 columns reports some data relative to a given person.

I want to build five rankings based on the values in the 5 columns of each group. For example, the ranking of the columns "A, F, K" should be "Bob, Charles, Alice" (because the value in A of Bob is 71, the value in A of Charles is 13, and the value in A of Alice is 10). Similarly, the ranking of "B, G, L" would either be "Alice, Charles, Bob" or "Charles, Alice, Bob" (because there is a tie: 35, 35, 15).

I suppose I should use a mix of INDEX/MATCH, (V)LOOKUP and LARGE but don't really know where to start. The furthest I got is something along the lines of

```
LARGE((A2, F2, K2), 1)
LARGE((A2, F2, K2), 2)
LARGE((A2, F2, K2), 3)
```

That (should) output the first, second and third largest value for the range "A2, F2, K2", but I don't know how to get to the name of the person related to that value from there. I have some troubles generalizing the examples I found with INDEX/MATCH and lookup functions to this atypical data structure (in groups of five columns).

EDIT: The names (Alice, Bob, Charles) are on merged cells.

Comment: You have certainly mentioned 'non-contiguous cells', however just to confirm, the names of people e.g. Alice, Bob, are they in a single cell with blanks in between or merged cells?

Comment: The names are on merged cells.

Comment: Are all 15 values always distinct? Can there be repeating values therein?

Comment: Yes, there can be repeated values, as explained in the second example for the ranking of B, G, L (there is a tie on the value 35, in that case the order in the ranking doesn't matter).

Comment: Is this the only data you have in your Excel file? e.g. Do you have repeating data in Row 3 & 4 on same lines as 1 & 2?

Comment: I do not have repeating data in Rows 3 & 4, but I have around 10 different "blocks" of 10 people say, each of whom has around 10 different values (in 10 columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Data differently in order to use Rank:

In E2 `=RANK($B2,$B2:$D2,0)`
In F2 `=RANK($C2,$B2:$D2,0)`
In G2 `=RANK($D2,$B2:$D2,0)`

And you can drag each formula in the same column

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution, but what I'm looking for is a Ranking where the content of the cells is a ranking with names, rather than with numbers.

This means that I need rankings that looks like

      Alice         Bob            Charles
      Bob          Charles       Bob
      Charles    Alice           Alice

Rather than a table with a number stating the people position in each rank

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a solution however it is only suitable if this is the only data in you sheet. If you have repeating rows below on similar lines on rows 1 & 2 then this shall become an inefficient solution and you may need to opt for VBA probably.

See the screenshot below.

The matrix is aligned in Range G7:J12.

Formula in H8

```
=IF(CHOOSE(1,$A$2,$F$2,$K$2)=LARGE(($A$2,$F$2,$K$2),1),$A$1,IF(CHOOSE(2,$A$2,$F$2,$K$2)=LARGE(($A$2,$F$2,$K$2),1),$F$1,$K$1))
```

H9

```
=IF(CHOOSE(1,$B$2,$G$2,$L$2)=LARGE(($B$2,$G$2,$L$2),1),$A$1,IF(CHOOSE(2,$B$2,$G$2,$L$2)=LARGE(($B$2,$G$2,$L$2),1),$F$1,$K$1))
```

H10

```
=IF(CHOOSE(1,$C$2,$H$2,$M$2)=LARGE(($C$2,$H$2,$M$2),1),$A$1,IF(CHOOSE(2,$C$2,$H$2,$M$2)=LARGE(($C$2,$H$2,$M$2),1),$F$1,$K$1))
```

H11

```
=IF(CHOOSE(1,$D$2,$I$2,$N$2)=LARGE(($D$2,$I$2,$N$2),1),$A$1,IF(CHOOSE(2,$D$2,$I$2,$N$2)=LARGE(($D$2,$I$2,$N$2),1),$F$1,$K$1))
```

H12

```
=IF(CHOOSE(1,$E$2,$J$2,$O$2)=LARGE(($E$2,$J$2,$O$2),1),$A$1,IF(CHOOSE(2,$E$2,$J$2,$O$2)=LARGE(($E$2,$J$2,$O$2),1),$F$1,$K$1))
```

Now drag the respective formulas across to the right and make a slight modification in the  LARGE function. For second column i.e. Col I put the second parameter as 2 for both LARGE therein and for the third column i.e. Col J, put it 3.

[image]

Honestly discard this solution if you have repeating rows below and you need to do it for every set or rows therein.

Comment: This is exactly the type of ranking I need. I'll try to adapt your example to my data, but as you suspected this is more complicated. I have around 10 people in total, each of whom has around 10 different types of data (say something like 10 rankings of length 10). I might be able to do it, but I think I need 9 of these "IF / CHOOSE" constructs, seems complicated.

Comment: Excel has limitation of 7 Nested IF's. Even maintaining 7 nested IF's is bulky too. There might be a smarter solution but this is what I could think of for the moment! If you are familiar with VBA Coding you can opt for that too as it will be less complex and solvable at a click of a button.